# Material UI Autocomplete - unchecking checkboxes in renderOption using Redux dispatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, material-ui

I have a checkbox rendered in renderOptions prop of Autocomplete. 
I can get the list of options selected using onChange `function(event: object, value: T | T[], reason: string) => void` from here the value parameter will give me the array of options selected and I can store them in my reducer.
But how can I uncheck some options from outside this Autocomplete using Redux dispatch

```
optionsArray = [{id: 1, title: "Abc"}
                {id: 2, title: "xyz"}
                {id: 3, title: "pqr"}]

       <Autocomplete
          multiple
          options={optionsArray}
          getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
          renderOption={(option, {selected}) => (
             <Box>
                <Checkbox
                  checked={selected}
                />
                {option.title}
              </Box>
          )}
          onChange={(event, options) => getSelectedOptions(options)}
          getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option.id === value.id}
          renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField
              {...params}
              variant="outlined"
              placeholder="Select"
            />
          )}
        />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works:

```js
import React, { useReducer } from "react";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";
import CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon from "@material-ui/icons/CheckBoxOutlineBlank";
import CheckBoxIcon from "@material-ui/icons/CheckBox";
import { Chip } from "@material-ui/core";

const icon = <CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon fontSize="small" />;
const checkedIcon = <CheckBoxIcon fontSize="small" />;

const options = [
  ...
];

const initialState = { selectedOptions: [] };

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_SELECTED_OPTIONS":
      return { selectedOptions: action.payload.options };

    case "REMOVE_OPTION":
      return {
        selectedOptions: state.selectedOptions.filter(
          (option) => option.id !== action.payload.id
        )
      };
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}

export default function App() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  const handleChange = (event, values) => {
    dispatch({ type: "SET_SELECTED_OPTIONS", payload: { options: values } });
  };

  const removeOption = (id) => {
    dispatch({ type: "REMOVE_OPTION", payload: { id: id } });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Autocomplete
        multiple
        options={options}
        disableCloseOnSelect
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
        value={state.selectedOptions}
        renderTags={(values) =>
          values.map((value) => (
            <Chip
              key={value.id}
              label={value.title}
              onDelete={() => {
                removeOption(value.id);
              }}
            />
          ))
        }
        getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option.id === value.id}
        renderOption={(option, { selected }) => (
          <React.Fragment>
            <Checkbox
              icon={icon}
              checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
              style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
              checked={selected}
            />
            {option.title}
          </React.Fragment>
        )}
        style={{ width: 500 }}
        onChange={handleChange}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            variant="outlined"
            label="Checkboxes"
            placeholder="Favorites"
          />
        )}
      />
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        color="secondary"
        onClick={() =>
          dispatch({
            type: "SET_SELECTED_OPTIONS",
            payload: {
              options: [
                {
                  id: 30,
                  title: "Once Upon a Time in the West",
                  year: 1968,
                  checked: false
                }
              ]
            }
          })
        }
      >
        Simulate changes from outside
      </Button>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(state, null, 2)}</pre>
    </>
  );
}
```

I simulated your redux store with the react useReducer function as you can see.
You just store the selected objects and when they are removed you just remove them too. For this you have to render the tag to have access to the onDelete function.
Now you can control the selected items from outside.

## Live Demo

[image: Edit material-ui-autocomplete-unchecking-checkboxes-in-renderoption-using-redux-dis]

Comment: but how will I initiate the action? I need to click on the checkbox and onClick doesn't work here

Comment: Ok sorry I misunderstood your question but I updated my answer and now it works as you desired.

Comment: that worked! the key thing I was missing was to use value prop in Autocomplete, so what I get from this is that value prop will have all selected options and that is used to render the checked options. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Sitesh Roy Yes you are absolutely wright. Keep in mind that I do not know how the values are changed without manual implementation. So if it is a mutable or inmutable change. This is important for redux, so I have manually set these functions in my example so that I know that the changes are immutable.